# Gensim Word2Vec or FastText build vocab from frequency

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, fasttext

I wonder what does `.build_vocab_from_freq()` function from gensim actually do? What is the difference when I'm not using it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It "builds a vocabulary from a dictionary of word frequencies". You need a vocabulary for your gensim models. Usually you build it from your corpus. This is basically an alternative option to build your vocabulary from a word frequencies dictionary. Word frequencies for example are usually used to filter low or high frequent words which are meaningless for your model.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Does it affect my model if I don't using it? Or, do you have any references for it? Thank you so much.